# SVN subversive. Eclipse. Local repository

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

We have a central svn repository where we can check-in  and commit new code. But I don't want to commit every minor change to central repository. So I want to create some local repository with Subversive SVN, which I can use for temporary committing (some minor bug-fixes, etc). It just for me, for comfort, for example: I make new functionality in 2 implementations, and I still don't know which implementation  commit to central repo, but in future I will commit one of it. So I need to save code of both implementations locally.

So if it possible to create local repository with subversive SVN  , how to do it? Or may be for my purpose exist some other, more elegant solution?

EDIT: When I used Mercurial, I get benefits of using Central(remote) repo, and local repo (so I can commit every minor big-fix locally, and every "big" change of project to central repo).

Comment: did you look at Git, or other DVCS repositories ? This looks exactly like what you are searching for...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Valentin : SVN does not provide any mechanism to separate a local commit and a remote one.
But GIT does, and is totally designed this way.

Unfortunately, it seams that your are working in a group, and maybe don't you have any choice on your version control system.
In that case, it's possible to share a GIT and a SVN repository on the same directory. GIT will help you having a local repository, where you'll be able to commit changes, create branches, and so on... And you will commit major changes on your remote SVN repo.

This solution works well. You just have to add the .git directory into SVN ignore file, and add the .svn directories into the GIT ignore file.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Git is so intelligent, that you can connect git to the svn repository. 
With a command:

```
git-svn clone -s http://example.com/my_subversion_repo local_dir
```

Read the detailed tutorial:
http://viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion